# Forward Emails preserving recipients (INDY and Delphi)

Tags: email, delphi, smtp, indy

I retrieve eMails from a GMail account with a TIdIMAP4-object and want to forward them with TIdSMTP to an other (GMail-)account while preserving the original list of recipients.

My approach was adding the destination address as BCC to make it invisible in the destination, but how can I prevent the SMTP component from sending it to all the other recipients in the list? They then would get all the forwarded mails twice.

UPDATE 1:
Instead of using BCC I provided the destination address in the send statement

```
smtp.Send(msg,destination);
```

but the message is still  sent to all the other recipients.

Comment: FYI, your update should be posted as an answer instead. See [Can I answer my own question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: Passing an explicit recipient list as a parameter to `Send()` will send the email ONLY to that list, it WILL NOT send the email to the recipients mentioned inside the email itself, as you claim.

Comment: Unfortunately it does (Delphi 10.3.3, Stock Indy) in my setup although I use the above code and created destination fresh filled with only the desired address in the list.

Comment: Sorry, you are RIGHT I must correct myself - the other recepients do not get the mail, For some strange reason the sent mail is visible in the Intray of the "relay" account. Thanks. If you put your ciomment as answer I will happily accept it!

Comment: I have posted an answer now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, `TIdSMTP.Send()` will send the email to all of the recipients listed in the `Recipients`, `CcList` and `BccList` properties of `TIdMessage`.

When you download an email into a `TIdMessage` via POP3 or IMAP, the `Recipients` and `CcList` (but not the `BccList`) are filled in from the email's existing `To` and `CC` headers, respectively.

When you then forward the email, if you do not want it to be sent to the recipients specified in the email, then you can call the overloaded version of `TIdSMTP.Send()` that takes a recipient list as a parameter. That will send the email ONLY to that list.  For example:

```pascal
var
  forwardTo: TIdEmailAddressList;
begin
  ...
  forwardTo := TIdEmailAddressList.Create;
  try
    // add desired recipients to forwardTo as needed, then...
    smtp.Send(msg, forwardTo);
  finally
    forwardTo.Free;
  end;
  ...
end;
```